# Subject ignores onNext from another observable

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I'm trying to make a stub of an object that should emit data to my `ViewModel`. To do that, I create a property and a Subject that notifies observers that this property has changed (as far as I know, I need a BehaviorSubject).

```
private var weekRecord: WeekRecord = emptyRecord()

private val subject = BehaviorSubject.create<WeekRecord>()
```

There are two methods: One is called from the main fragment's ViewModel while the other is called from ViewModels of all fragments of the `ViewPager` which is placed in the main fragment.

The first method should load data from the server and save it in some storage and then notify the main fragment that loading is complete.

```
// MainViewModel subscribes to this completable and observes it on mainThread
fun loadWeek(): Completable {
    return Completable.fromCallable {
            // pretend that we are loading data from server and saving it in the storage
            createFakeRecord()
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .delaySubscription(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}

fun createFakeRecord() {
    weekRecord = // some fake record
    // notify observers that storage content changed
    subject.onNext(weekRecord)
}
```

The second method returns observable so that the pages can track relevant changes in storage.

```
// PageViewModel subscribes to this observable and observes it on mainThread 
fun loadDayRecord(dayId: Int): Observable<DayRecord> {
    return subject
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map { week ->
            // extract day that this observer needs
            week.dayRecordList[dayId]
        }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
}
```

Subscription in the PageViewModel:

```
dayObserver = taskUseCase
        .loadDayRecord(dayId)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { record ->
                Log.d("Page", record.date.toString())
            },
            { e ->
                Log.e("Page", e.message, e)
            }
        )
```

The problem is that the subject seems to ignore the item that I pass in `onNext` in the `createFakeRecord()`. After 10 seconds of delay, the main fragment is notified of completion but page fragments do not receive anything. How should I pass new values?

Comment: It seems like new value passed correclty to the subject and the reason is somewhere else. How do you subscribe to this subject?

Comment: @Demigod check updated details in question

Comment: @Demigod I tried to call createFakeRecord() in loadDayRecord() outside of rx-sequence and the passed value was emited. I thought that the problem is in threads, but even when I changed loadWeek's subscribeOn to mainThread nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the way the items emited, by accident I forgot to specify the scope of the stub dependency in Dagger and so every fragment got it's own instance of the stub object, but only the first one had it's data loaded.